# How to pass number of displayed listings on page in URL in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following laravel project tutorial from Youtube that uses pagination function in controller like:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('listings.index', [
            'listings' => Listing::latest()->filter(request(['tag', 'search']))->paginate(3)
        ]);
    }
```

In index.blade.php pagination layout is displayed with `{{$listings->links()}}` and i want to include the number of listings that's displayed per page in URL like `?per_page=3`. My assumption was that I have to switch number of displayed listings parameter with variable like `paginate($perPage)` but it didn't work out. I made the route `Route::get('/per_page/{perPage}', [ListingController::class, 'index']);`. After that I tried making separate public function that uses `perPage()` function however it also didn't work out. This is my second day of using laravel and I'm sure I'm doing stupid mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{{$meals->links()}}` you can try like this

Comment: Sry, i copied wrong function there. I edited and corrected the function. Im rly tired and didnt even notice that.

Comment: What is the thing you want to do, there is no problem here

Comment: If you define `Route::get('/per_page/{perPage}', ...)`, then you can navigate to `http://localhost:8000/per_page/3` (etc.), but you also need to add `public function index($perPage = 3)`, and use that `$perPage` like `paginate($perPage)`. That is how URL parameters work. If you want to use a Query String, like `http://localhost:8000/per_page?perPage=3`, then you'd use `public function index(Request $request)`, then `paginate($request->input('perPage', 3)`. Please read the documentation on URL parameters and Query String parameters, or clarify your problem (i.e. what isn't working right now)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string, etc.

Comment: Sry, i tried both so i lost myself. I want to use Query String like http://localhost:8000/?per_page=3. having possibility of modificating number of listings displayed by changing that number from url. I'll look up the documentation you sent me, tnx. @TimLewis

Comment: Then you'd modify `public function index()` to `public function index(Request $request)`, and `->paginate($request->input('per_page', 3))`. Navigating to `http://localhost:8000/?per_page=5` would return 5 rows per page, `http://localhost:8000/` would be 3 (the `, 3` is the "fallback"), etc. 

Comment: Thank you so much. :) I created paginations hard way before using plain php by passing sql querys in variables and using a lot of if statements juggling between number of pages, active and $last_page so using frameworks like laravel is super confusing and ovherwhelming. You clerified a lot of things to me now.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I have done the same as well; managing the base query, using `SKIP` and `TAKE` (or `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, etc.), hooking it into Query String parameters, etc. was and still is a pain in base PHP. Laravel comes with a lot of overhead, but is honestly so much nicer to work in. Also, it has fantastic documentation, like https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination. When combined with other things, like the `request` Object, Query/URL parameters, etc., stuff is so much simpler. Cheers, and happy coding! 